# Laravel - Get users for tickers

Tags: php, laravel

I understand this might be really simple but I cannot get my head around it.

Say I am fetching all tickets

```
$tickets  = Ticket::all();
```

And with a single line, I want to fetch all the users associated with each ticker, (every ticket has a field with `user_id`), is there a single line of code, which can do it in Laravel. I can do the old way to loop though each ticket and fecth the details for each user as below, but am just looking for best practices here.

```
foreach($tickets as $ticket):
     $ticket->user = User::find($ticket->user_id);
endforeach;
```

Comment: Try using relationship via eloquent https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many

Comment: @Regolith thanks a lot for pointing me to the resource.

Comment: Your way would also cause many more SQL queries which would be extremely slow the more rows there are in the DB. You theoretically want to minimize the number of SQL queries made by Laravel.

Comment: Just add `with('user')` if you have already created relationship b/w `ticket`<=> `user`

Comment: Like: `$tickets  = Ticket::with('user')->all();` in such case you din't need to set the userinfo separatly... it would be set automatically where user associated with ticket.

Comment: I think you can not modify the query performed with `all()`, use `get()` instead: `$tickets = Ticket::with('user')->get();`

Answer (score 2):

i'm assuming you have defined a correct relationship in your models.

You can use eloquent relationship of laravel to get all tickets of users

```
$tickets = User::with('tickets')->get();
```

to get data if user has at least one ticket you can use the below code

```
$tickets = User::has('tickets')->get();
```

To get all tickets only:

```
$tickets = Ticket::all();
```

and then in your blade you can do:

```
@foreach($tickets as $ticket)
 // getting user using relationship
 {{ $ticket->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

or to get tickets associated with user you can use

```
$tickets = Ticket::whereHas('user', function ($q) {
                       $q->with('user');
                   })
                   ->get();
```

to know more about relationships visit [this](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many)

Comment: I think this will give me the list of users and all the tickets associated to the user. What I want is, I want to get the list of all tickets, and the user associated with the tickets.

Answer (score 1):

The first, you declare relation model `Ticket` with model `User`:

This is code in model `Ticket`:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Model\User', 'user_id', 'id'); //id is the primary key in User table
}
```

then fetching all tickets with user info

```
$tickets  = Ticket::load('user')->all();
```

or

```
$tickets  = Ticket::with('user')->all();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the list of all tickets where has user, with the user associated with each ticket, try this:

```
$tickets = Ticket::whereHas('user', function ($query) {
                       $query->with('user');
                   })
                   ->get();
```

If you are sure that all tickets have an associated user, use this:

```
$tickets = Ticket::with('user')->get();
```